# Importing Modules in D

Tags: module, d

I am trying to use basic module importing in D (language release 2). As a guide I used example on dlang.org but my simple program will not compile. The files are in the same directory.

Here is my main.d file's contents:

```
import std.stdio;
import mymodule;

void main(string[] args){
  sayHello();
  writeln("Executing Main");
}
```

And here is my module file's contents (mymodule.d):

```
void sayHello(){
  writeln("hello");

}
```

To compile I execute via bash:

```
dmd main.d
```

And the error output is:

```
main.o: In function `_Dmain':
main.d:(.text._Dmain+0x5): undefined reference to `_D8mymodule8sayHelloFZv'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
```

Comment: That worked. Post it as a proper answer so I can give you the recognition. You deserve it!  Even if you do not care about the points, at least that way I can mark the question as answered.

Comment: Just use rdmd --build-only main.d.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You need to list all of the modules that you're compiling on the command line. If you don't list a module, then it won't be compiled. The modules that *are* compiled will be able to use the uncompiled modules, since the compiler pulls in their declarations, but the compiler generates no object files for them. So, when the linker goes to link, it will complain that that there are definitions missing. In this case, it complains about the fact that `mymodule.sayHello` hasn't been defined.

   If you want the compiler to automatically search for all of the modules that the first module imports and compile them all for you, then you're going to need to use rdmd, which is a wrapper for dmd, which comes with dmd. dmd itself doesn't do that. It only compiles the modules that you tell it to.
2. You haven't imported `std.stdio` in mymodule. So, even if you do `dmd main.d mymodule.d` like you should be (or even better, `dmd -w main.d mymodule.d` or `dmd -wi main.d mymodule.d`), it'll fail to compile mymodule, because `writeln` hasn't been declared. The fact that main.d imported it has no effect on mymodule.
3. While it's not a big deal in this case, you really should put a `module modulename;` declaration at the top of your modules. The compiler will infer the module name from the filename, but once you have subpackages, you *need* to do it, or you'll have importing problems, because only the filename is inferred, not the package names. So, if you have `foo/bar/mod.d`, and you don't have a `module` declaration in `mod.d`, it'll be inferred as `mod`, not `foo.bar.mod`.

Answer (score 5):

`dmd mymodule.d main.d`

The only languages I know that are smart enough to work out dependencies on their own are Go and Haskell.

Comment: `rdmd` will work out the dependencies. `rdmd main.d` would build the file and all dependencies and execute the result. If you only want to build add `--build-only` to the command.

Comment: I love that feature in Haskell.  I wish D had it too.

Comment: To be pedantic, I don't think either Go or Haskell have that feature but rather their compilers do. A conformant D compiler could have it as well.

Comment: At least in the case of go, the tooling really is part of the language. As far as haskell goes, I probably should have been pedantic  and said "ghc", but really, who isn't using ghc these days?

Comment: It can't be done i think because in D you can have foo.bar.module (the same name!) in different directories! Go and Haskell probably do not have ability to specify different source paths?